# Remove leading zeros of decimals in pig

Tags: regex, decimal, apache-pig

Is there any way to remove leading zeros of decimals in pig?

eg: 000965.326 -> 965.326

number of digit can vary so cannot simply substring fixed number of digits.

Also, I have tried this but not working for decimals

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'0*(\\d+)?', 1);
DUMP B;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match `0's` and replace them with '' (empty string).

[Live demo on regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=93ef84c8-ad18-419c-a0b1-96b86f4b9299) with replacement.

Answer (score 2):

```
REPLACE(yourDecimal, '^0+', '');
```